# Javascript alter key in object before console.log

Tags: javascript, object

something inexplicable to me appears in the result of this code

```
var ctrl1 = {
    func1: function(objct){
        objct.options.b = "b";
    }
}

var ctrl2 = {
    myvar : {options:{a:"a"}},
    func2: function(){
        console.log(ctrl2.myvar);
        ctrl1.func1(ctrl2.myvar);
    },
}

ctrl2.func2();
```

I had as results

```
Object {a:"a", b:"b"}
```

while normally it should display

```
Object {a:"a"}
```

test in http://jsfiddle.net/akbach/6u0qnrc6/4/

Comment: yeah, somehow next line (`ctrl1.func1(ctrl2.myvar);`) is affecting the value printed in the `console.log(ctrl2.myvar);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your coding is working fine. It's the options which gets updated before printing in console.

Try following steps open you console paste following code.

```
var ctrl1 = {
    func1: function(objct){
        objct.options.b = "b";
    }
}

var ctrl2 = {
    myvar : {options:{a:"a"}},
    func2: function(){
        console.log(ctrl2.myvar);
        debugger;
        ctrl1.func1(ctrl2.myvar);
    },
}

ctrl2.func2();
```

Once the code stops at debugger you will see the required result in you console i.e a:"a"

Now resume script execution. After that write `ctrl2.myvar` on you console and then you will see the updated options with both a and b.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` may display a live reference (in chrome anyway), and not a snapshot. If it is "folded" (have to click on it to expand the details), it will continue to update.

You can see this by running your code, then modifying it again in the console and watching the previous output.

Answer (score 0):

console.log() method receives a reference to the object. To open the object in console by clicking on "+" we need longer time, than the need for call func1 method. Try to replace console.log(ctrl2.myvar); with console.log(JSON.stringify(ctrl2.myvar));